# How to get early stopping for lasso regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, lasso-regression, early-stopping

I have a problem. Is there an option to get early stopping? Because I saw on a plot that I get Overfitting after a while, so I want to get the most optimal.

```py
dfListingsFeature_regression = pd.read_csv(r"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Coderanker3/dataset4/main/listings_cleaned.csv")
d = {True: 1, False: 0, np.nan : np.nan} 
dfListingsFeature_regression['host_is_superhost'] = dfListingsFeature_regression[
                                                             'host_is_superhost'].map(d).astype('int')

X = dfListingsFeature_regression.drop(columns=['host_id', 'id', 'price']) # Features
y = dfListingsFeature_regression['price'] # Target variable
print(dfListingsFeature_nor.shape)


steps = [('feature_selection', SelectFromModel(estimator=LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000))),
         ('lasso', Lasso(alpha=0.1))]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps) 

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=30)


parameteres = { }

grid = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameteres, cv=5)                
grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
                    
print("score = %3.2f" %(grid.score(X_test,y_test)))
print('Training set score: ' + str(grid.score(X_train,y_train)))
print('Test set score: ' + str(grid.score(X_test,y_test)))

# Prediction
y_pred = grid.predict(X_test)

print("RMSE Val:", metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred, squared=False))

y_train_predict = grid.predict(X_train)
print("Train:" , metrics.mean_squared_error(y_train, y_train_predict , squared=False))

r2 = metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
print(r2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean applying regularization. In this case, we can reduce the chance of overfitting with l1 regularization or Lasso regression.

This regularization strategy is a kind of "feature selection" when you have several features, as it would shrink coefficients of non informative features toward zero.

In this case, you wanto to find the optimal `alpha` value that finds the best score in the test dataset. Additionally you can plot the gap difference between train/test score to guide your decision.

The stronger the alpha value the stronger the regularization. See code example below.

**Full Example**

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_validate
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X, y = make_regression(noise=4, random_state=0)

# Alphas to search over
alphas = list(np.linspace(2e-2, 1, 20))

results = {}

for alpha in alphas:
    
    print(f'Fitting Lasso(alpha={alpha})')
    
    estimator = Lasso(alpha=alpha, random_state=0)

    cv_results = cross_validate(
        estimator, X, y, cv=5, return_train_score=True, scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error'
    )
    
    # Comput average metric value
    avg_train_score = np.mean(cv_results['train_score']) * -1
    
    avg_test_score = np.mean(cv_results['test_score']) * -1
    
    results[alpha] = (avg_train_score, avg_test_score)

train_scores = [v[0] for v in results.values()]
test_scores = [v[1] for v in results.values()]
gap_scores = [v[1] - v[0] for v in results.values()]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))

ax1.set_title('Alpha values vs Avg score')
ax1.plot(results.keys(), train_scores, label='Train Score')
ax1.plot(results.keys(), test_scores, label='Test Score')
ax1.legend()

ax2.set_title('Train/Test Score Gap')
ax2.plot(results.keys(), gap_scores)
```

[image]

Notice than when `alpha` is close to zero it is overfitting and when lambda gets bigger it is underfitting. However, around `alpha=0.4` we can find a balance between underfitting and overfitting the data.

Comment: @Test does this answer helps your question? I think in general you mean regularization.